# How to read into a select html using php

Tags: php, html

I have to create a website for a homework at school. It is my first time doing it, so I'm encountering some problems. 
Usually I can find a solution but this time i didn't. Anyway, 
I'm trying to read the selected option in a select list in html using php, but I'm getting an "Undefined index" everytime, I don't know why.

I have tried to change the name of the select, put it in a form, notig is working.

```
<form method="post">
                    <select name="licenceOptions" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
                        <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
                    </select>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    $selected_val = $_POST['licenceOptions'];
                    echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;

                    ?>
```

This is the error I get :

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: licenceOptions in C:\wamp64\www\Projet_Technique\DacorrecillasV1.php on line 60
```

Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0022  403904  {main}( )   ...\DacorrecillasV1.php:0

Comment: The form must be submitted, in this case back to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">
        <select name="licenceOptions" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" onChange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
        <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></noscript>
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['licenceOptions'])){
        echo 'You have selected :' . $_POST['licenceOptions'];
    }
?>
```

The input button is hide and it's used when you change something in the select.
The empty option is the default option cause you can't use the choice 1 without it.

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` should do it (see the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)). It checks if a value "is set" before it bothers trying to evaluate it.

Because your PHP is only processed *before* the page is loaded, you won't have a value in `$_POST['licenseOptions']` until your form is submitted to that same page and it can re-generate your markup with the new values in `$_POST`.

Because you probably don't want to display your "You have selected..." message until you actually have a selection, try wrapping that block like this:

```
    <?php
         if(isset($_POST['licenceOptions'])){
            $selected_val = $_POST['licenceOptions'];
            echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;
         }
    ?>
```

Just remember what others have pointed out: you still need the user to *submit* the form before your PHP code can see their choice!

Comment: Also need a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment of AbraCadaver above with some sample code:

```
<select name="licenceOptions" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
    <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['licenceOptions'])) {
        $selected_val = $_POST['licenceOptions'];
        echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;
    }
 ?>
```